# Set DataSource For jQuery DataTable to PHP JSON Encoded Array

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using the below code to query MySql and return the results to an array.  I have verified with a for each loop that this has my results as expected.

My last step of this process is to set this php array as the datasource for the jQuery Datatable?  I have the below code but my DataTable is never created.

What am I missing?

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("site", "user", "psasswr=ord", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$data = [];

foreach ($result as $row) {
   $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<script>
var dataSet = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Title" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

**EDIT**
As requested this is what my JSON looks like if I do a `echo json_encode($data)`

```
[{"Salesman":"Harris Teeter","Title":"Manager","Office":"Home","Salary":"0.000000"}]
```

Comment: Can you share the output json from your PHP?

Comment: take note DataTables has its own json format, you have to conform to it

Comment: @atymic - see my edit.  It includes the requested info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use **data** instead of **title** in datatable function.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { data: "Name" },
        { data: "Title" },
        { data: "Office" },
        { data: "Salary" }
    ]
} );
```

Second, you need to modify your JSON like below:

```
[{"Name":"Harris Teeter","Title":"Manager","Office":"Home","Salary":"0.000000"}]
```

Here is working JSFiddle : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gqbyujvp/3/)